# kerasで同じコードでIndexErrorとAttributeErrorがでます

Tags: python3, 機械学習, keras

自力で単純なautoencoderを頑張って書いてみました。
しかし、

```
C:\Users\yudai\Desktop\keras_AE.py:62: UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API: `Model(inputs=Tensor("in..., outputs=Tensor("de...)`
  autoencoder = Model(input=input_word, output=decoded)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yudai\Desktop\keras_AE.py", line 70, in <module>
    shuffle=False)
  File "C:\Users\yudai\Anaconda3\envs\pyMLgpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\yudai\Anaconda3\envs\pyMLgpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 139, in fit_loop
    if issparse(ins[i]) and not K.is_sparse(feed[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

と出力されます。
もし原因がわかる方がいらっしゃるならば、
何卒、ご教授宜しくお願い致します。
（[Terateilでも質問](https://teratail.com/questions/153594)しています）

追記:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7602
より

```
autoencoder = Model(input=input_word, output=decoded)
```

を

```
autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_word, outputs=decoded)
```

に直しました。
しかし、同じエラーが出ます。
いくつか他のエラーがありましたが、修正しました。

入力データの問題かどうかを調べるため、下に示しているC:\Users\hoge\Desktop\poem.txtのように漢字空間あり、漢字空間なし、ひらがな空間あり、ひらがな空間なし、また、それぞれ行替えでありなしを試してみましたが、すべて同じエラーがでます。

違うWindows 10のPCでは、
python 3.6.5
tensorflow 1.8.0
keras 2.1.5

```
C:\Users\hoge\Desktop\keras_AE.py:62: UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API: `Model(inputs=Tensor("in..., outputs=Tensor("de...)`
  autoencoder = Model(input=input_word, output=decoded)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hoge\Desktop\keras_AE.py", line 70, in <module>
    shuffle=False)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1630, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1487, in _standardize_user_data
    in zip(y, sample_weights, class_weights, self._feed_sample_weight_modes)]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1486, in <listcomp>
    for (ref, sw, cw, mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 540, in _standardize_weights
    return np.ones((y.shape[0],), dtype=K.floatx())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

が同じコードで違うエラーがでます。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
import numpy as np
import codecs

#データの前処理
#データの読み込み
with codecs.open(r'C:\Users\yudai\Desktop\poem.txt', 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    for text in f:
        text = text.strip()
#コーパスの長さ
print('corpus length:', len(text))
#文字数を数えるため、textをソート
chars = sorted(list(set(text)))
#全文字数の表示
print('total chars:', len(chars))
#文字をID変換
char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
#IDから文字へ変換
indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
#テキストを17文字ずつ読み込む
maxlen = 17
#サンプルバッチ数
step = 3
sentences = []
next_chars = []
for i in range(0, len(text) - maxlen, step):
    sentences.append(text[i: i + maxlen])
    next_chars.append(text[i + maxlen])
#学習する文字数を表示
print('Sequences:', len)

#ベクトル化する
print('Vectorization...')
x = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
        x[i, t, char_indices[char]] = 1
    y[i, char_indices[next_chars[i]]] = 1

#モデルを構築する工程に入る
print('Build model...')
#encoderの次元
encoding_dim = 128
#入力用の変数
input_word = Input(shape=(x ,y))
#入力された語がencodeされたものを格納する
encoded_h1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_word)
encoded_h2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded_h1)
encoded_h3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded_h2)
#潜在変数（実質的な主成分分析）
latent = Dense(8, activation='relu')(encoded_h3)
#encodeされたデータを再構成
decoded_h1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(latent)
decoded_h2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(decoded_1)
decoded_h3 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(encoded_2)

output = Dense(100, activation)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_word, outputs=decoded)
#Adamで最適化、loss関数をcategorical_crossentropy
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='Adam', 
loss='categorical_crossentropy')

#autoencoderの実行
autoencoder.fit(x_train,
                epoch=1000,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=False)
#学習の進み具合を観察
def on_epoch_end(epoch):
    print()
    print('Epoch: %d' % epoch)

#モデルの構造を保存
model_json = autoencoder.to_json()
with open('keras_AE.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
#学習済みモデルの重みを保存
autoencoder.save_weights('AE.h5')

decoded_word = autoencoder.predict(word_test)

X_embedded = model.predict(X_train)
autoencoder.fit(X_embedded,X_embedded,epochs=10,
            batch_size=256, validation_split=.1)
```

C:\Users\hoge\Desktop\poem.txtは、webから２万９０００件の俳句を一文ずつ抽出し、MeCabで形態素解析を行っています。
例：
朝霧 の 中 に 九段 の ともし 哉
あたたか な 雨 が 降る なり 枯葎
菜の花 や は つと 明るき 町 は づれ
秋風 や 伊予 へ 流る る 汐 の 音
長閑 さ や 障子 の 穴 に 海 見え て
若鮎 の 二 手 に なりて 上り けり
行く 秋 を す つく と 鹿 の 立ち に けり
我 声 の 風 に なり けり 茸狩
毎年 よ 彼岸の入り に 寒い の は

## 環境

Windows 10

python 3.7.0
tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0
keras 2.2.4

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/153532

Comment: すみません。マルチポストをしてしまいました。https://teratail.com/questions/153594　いけないことだとは思っていませんでした。今度からは無いように気を付けます。

Comment: マルチポストについてteratailでのルールは「投稿先を明記してください」となっているようですが、スタックオーバーフローでは特に禁止等のルールはありません。ですが基本的にはteratailと同じように、予め質問文に明記してもらった方が"親切"かなと思います。重複したやり取りをあちこちでするのは、質問者・回答者双方にとって無駄な労力と時間を費やすことになります。

Comment: かしこまりました。自身の他人への配慮が足りていませんでした。この件に関しましては、質問文にteratailへのurlを明記するという形にさせて頂きます。

Comment: cubick さん、フォローありがとうございます。yudaitonoyama さん、追記ありがとうございました。

Comment: いえ。こちらこそご指摘いただき大変感謝しております。

Comment: mjyさん、質問を修正していただきありがとうございます。

Comment: teratailでもmjyさんの修正を参考にしました。

Answer (score 1):

terailでtiitoiが答えてくださいました。

まず AutoEncoder は入力と出力を同じデータにして学習するものですよね。
なので、入力が正解データでもあるわけで、fit(x) と入力しか渡していないため、'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' とエラーになっています。

```
autoencoder.fit(x, x,
            epochs=1000,
            batch_size=256,
            shuffle=False)
```

次に入力に対して、入力と同じデータを出力させたいわけなので、出力層の形状を
    `decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(encoded)`
ではなく、入力と同じ以下のようにする必要があります。
    `decoded = Dense(12, activation='relu')(encoded)`

コード全文です。

```
import numpy as np
import codecs
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model

#データの読み込み
with open(r'test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    poems = f.read().splitlines()
text = poems[0]  # 1個目のデータ
print(text)

# コーパスの長さ
print('corpus length:', len(text))

# 文字数を数えるため、textをソート
chars = sorted(list(set(text)))

# 全文字数の表示
print('total chars:', len(chars))

# 文字をID変換
char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

# IDから文字へ変換
indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

#テキストを17文字ずつ読み込む
maxlen = 17
#サンプルバッチ数
step = 3
sentences = []
next_chars = []
for i in range(0, len(text) - maxlen, step):
    sentences.append(text[i: i + maxlen])
    next_chars.append(text[i + maxlen])
#学習する文字数を表示
print('Sequences:', sentences)
print('next_chars:', next_chars)

#ベクトル化する
print('Vectorization...')
x = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
        x[i, t, char_indices[char]] = 1
    y[i, char_indices[next_chars[i]]] = 1

#モデルを構築する工程に入る
print('Build model...')
#encoderの次元
encoding_dim = 128
#入力用の変数
input_word = Input(shape=(maxlen, len(chars)))
#入力された語がencodeされたものを格納する
encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_word)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)
#潜在変数（実質的な主成分分析）
latent = Dense(8, activation='relu')(encoded)
#encodeされたデータを再構成
decoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(latent)
decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(12, activation='relu')(encoded)
autoencoder = Model(input=input_word, output=decoded)
#Adamで最適化、loss関数をcategorical_crossentropy
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
autoencoder.summary()

print(x.shape)
#autoencoderの実行
autoencoder.fit(x, x,
                epochs=1000,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=False)

#モデルの構造を保存
model_json = autoencoder.to_json()
with open('keras_AE.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
#学習済みモデルの重みを保存
autoencoder.save_weights('AE.h5')
```